# Regex: Extract specific value from URL

Tags: python, regex, pandas, parsing, dataframe

I am having some trouble to exact the string from URL using re library.

here's an example:

```
http://www.example.it/remoteconnexion.aspx?u=xxxxx@abc.it&direction=vente.aspx%3pid%xx123%63abcd"
```

I have a dataframe and i want to add a column using a value from another column, in this example df['URL_REG'] contains: '123'?

```
df['URL_REG'] = df['URL'].map(lambda x : re.findall(r'[REGEX]+', x)[0])
```

the structure of URL can change but the part that i want comes always between 'direction=vente.aspx%3pid%' and '%'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vectorized [Series.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [50]: df['URL_REG'] = df.URL.str.extract(r'direction=vente.aspx\%3pid\%([^\%]+)\%*',
                                            expand=False)

In [51]: df
Out[51]:
                                                 URL URL_REG
0  http://www.example.it/remoteconnexion.aspx?u=x...   xx123
```

**UPDATE:**

> i want only '123' part instead of 'xx123', where 'xx' is a hexademical number

```
In [53]: df['URL_REG'] = df.URL.str.extract(r'direction=vente.aspx\%3pid\%\w{2}(\d+)\%*', 
                                            expand=False)

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
                                                 URL URL_REG
0  http://www.example.it/remoteconnexion.aspx?u=x...     123
```

Comment: its works, but i just forgot to mark that i want only '123' part instead of 'xx123'

Comment: @Omar14, do you have `%xx` in the URL or are those `xx` - digits?

Comment: most of the time i have one digit and one letter. '3d123' where xx = 3d.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
import re

url='http://www.example.it/remoteconnexion.aspxu=xxxxx@abc.it&direction=vente.aspx%3pid%xx123%63abcd'
output = re.findall('3pid%(.*?)%', url)

print(output)
```

Output:

```
['xx123']
```

Then apply the same pattern to your DataFrame.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(['http://www.example.it/remoteconnexion.aspx?u=xxxxx@abc.it&direction=vente.aspx%3pid%xx123%63abcd'], columns = ['URL'])

output = df['URL'].apply(lambda x : re.findall('3pid%(.*?)%', x))

print(output)

# Or, maybe if you want to return the url and the data captured:
# output = df['URL'].apply(lambda x : (x, re.findall('3pid%(.*?)%', x)))
# output[0]
# >>> ('http://www.example.it/remoteconnexion.aspx?u=xxxxx@abc.it&direction=vente.aspx%3pid%xx123%63abcd', 
#   ['xx123'])
```

Output:

```
0    [xx123]
Name: URL, dtype: object
```